# Umlaut script does work on my device but not on a friends

Tags: autohotkey

I'm running into a problem with an AutoHotkey script I made for myself to type German texts on my english keyboard.
As it works great for me, I wanted to share it with a friend, but strangely when I try to run it on a friends PC it does result in strange outputs:

```
Ä -> Ã„  
ä -> Ã¤  
Ö -> Ã–  
ö -> Ã¶  
Ü -> Ãœ  
ü -> Ã¼  
ß -> ÃŸ
```

The ~ does not work at all and the ° is the only working hotkey.

Here is the script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.\
!+A::
Send, Ä
return
!a::
Send, ä
return
!+O::
Send, Ö
return
!o::
Send, ö
return
!+U::
Send, Ü
return
!u::
Send, ü
return
!s::
Send, ß
return
!e::
Send, €
return
!m::
Send, µ
return
!d::
Send, °
return
!]::
Send, {Alt down}{Numpad1}{Numpad2}{Numpad6}{Alt up}
return
^!#right::
Run C:\Users\cmcdi\Documents\Shortcuts\display64.exe /rotate:90
return
```

If you need any more information, I'll be happy to provide them.

Comment: Looks like UTF-8 vs Cp1252 usage.

Comment: Okay, that was what I thought of first as well, but I checked the ahk file and it is UTF-8. So should I try to save it in Cp1252? I'll give it a try as soon as I get home agan. Thank you!

Comment: See also: [Why are the non-ASCII characters in my script displaying or sending incorrectly?](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#nonascii)

Comment: @Carroll A file itself has no encoding, it all depends on what character set is used when reading it. The behaviour suggests that on your friends PC it is read as Cp1252.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did save the file using the ASCII option and it worked well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely an encoding issue as people in the comments have noted, however you may also experience some unexpected behavior with `Send` when *normally* sending characters that don't exists in the current keyboard layout.
A good way to get around this, and to not have to worry about any encoding issues, is to specify these *special* characters with the [Unicode character notation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Unicode).

Also, since you have one-liner hotkeys, you can omit `Return`s and do it like this:

```
!+A::SendInput, {U+00C4}
!a::SendInput, {U+00E4}
!+O::SendInput, {U+00D6}
!o::SendInput, {U+00F6}
```

To get the Unicodes for characters, you can use e.g. [this](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%C3%84%C3%A4%C3%96%C3%B6) website.
I'm also using [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) instead of `Send`, since it's just good practice to do so. Even though it makes no difference here whatsoever (as described in my above link about the Unicode character notation).

And also, your script seems include the autogenerated ahk code at the top, which specifies [`SendMode, Input`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm), which means all instances of `Send` are automatically converted to `SendInput`.
All of the autogenerated code at the top can be removed if you want a nice lightweight script. None of the stuff in there is doing anything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your problem will most likely be a character encoding issue, I decided to throw in my special character solution. You can type two characters to create special characters.
Example  <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> will write  <kbd>à</kbd> or  <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> will write <kbd>ß</kbd>. I also use the <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> to create characters like <kbd>ö</kbd> or <kbd>é</kbd>. Since I use the Umlaut far more than accent aigu, I decided to "swap" the function of the <kbd>'/"</kbd> key. So to write <kbd>ö</kbd>, I press the <kbd>'/"</kbd> key and then <kbd>'o"</kbd>. If I want to write the <kbd>é</kbd>, I press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'/"</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> to get <kbd>é</kbd>. The "disadvantage" of this method is that if you need a single <kbd>"</kbd>, you will need to press <kbd>'/"</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>.

```
    ;================================== SPECIAL CHARACTERS FOR US KEYBOARD ==================================
:?C*:`` :: ; Turn `{Space} into neutral `, else ` will be used in next vowel.
    Send, ``{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:``a::à
:?C*:``i::ì
:?C*:``e::è
:?C*:``o::ò
:?C*:``u::ù
:?C*:``A::À
:?C*:``I::Ì
:?C*:``E::È
:?C*:``O::Ò
:?C*:``U::Ù

:?C*:^ :: ; Turn ^{Space} into neutral ^, else ^ will be used in next vowel.
    Send, {^}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:^a::â
:?C*:^i::î
:?C*:^e::ê
:?C*:^o::ô
:?C*:^u::û
:?C*:^A::Â
:?C*:^I::Î
:?C*:^E::Ê
:?C*:^O::Ô
:?C*:^U::Û

:?C*:`" :: ; Turn "{Space} into neutral ", else " will be used in next vowel.
    Send, +{'}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:`'a::ä
:?C*:`;a::ä
:?C*:`'i::ï
:?C*:`;i::ï
:?C*:`'e::ë
:?C*:`;e::ë
:?C*:`'o::ö
:?C*:`;o::ö
:?C*:`'u::ü
:?C*:`;u::ü
:?C*:`'A::Ä
:?C*:`'I::Ï
:?C*:`'E::Ë
:?C*:`'O::Ö
:?C*:`'U::Ü

:?C*:' :: ; Turn '{Space} into neutral ', else ' will be used in next vowel.
    Send, {'}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:`"a::á
:?C*:`"i::í
:?C*:`"e::é
:?C*:`"o::ó
:?C*:`"u::ú
:?C*:`"A::Á
:?C*:`"I::Í
:?C*:`"E::É
:?C*:`"O::Ó
:?C*:`"U::Ú

:?C*:`'c::ç
:?C*:`'C::Ç
:?C*:ss]::ß
:?C*:sss::ß
:?C*:ae]::æ
:?C*:AE]::Æ
:?C*:oe]::œ
:?C*:OE]::Œ
```

Answer (score 0):

The following AutoHotkey script works fine for me. It uses Unicode key strokes for a given special character.

```
; ------------------
; Deutsch special chars
; ------------------

!a::
Send, {U+00E4} ; ä
return
!+a::
Send, {U+00C4} ; Ä
return
!o::
Send, {U+00F6} ; ö
return
!+o::
Send, {U+00D6} ; Ö
return
!u::
Send, {U+00FC} ; ü
return
!+u::
Send, {U+00DC} ; Ü
return
!s::
Send, {U+00DF} ; ß
return
```